# Eclipse Error After Exporting

Tags: java, eclipse

I updated my project's code, and re-export it using Eclipse, and I ran it in Eclipse, no errors. But when I exported it as a Executable Jar File, "javaw.exe" shows up in task manager for a second then disappears, so I decided to start it using command prompt, and I got this error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0F6u.jpg

Whats wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong is you got a `NullPointerException` in a `static` block.

Comment: Why is it throwing a 
    NullPointerException
 now, but not in Eclipse?

Comment: If you right click the cmd titlebar, you can choose the option: mark, select your text then use the edit option to copy the text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, the exception occurs when you try to load the image. I'm guessing the image is in the jar but you are using the constructor that takes the string filename. Since that file is in the jar, you cannot access it that way. Instead use `getResource` which returns a URL.

You could do something like:

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource('/path/to/your/image');
new ImageIcon(url);
```

Comment: My Code: `static URL creditsbuttonpic = start.class.getResource("graphics//buttons//credits.png");`



`static JLabel credits = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(creditsbuttonpic));`

Comment: No double slashes needed. Also, depending on where you're loading the file from, it may be better to use an absolute file path (start with `/`) - remember in this case absolute, it's still relative to your classpath, not to your filesystem (e.g. the root dir is your top level classpath).

Comment: Yes it works! Thanks and its kind of confusing when to use \\ instead of  \ and vice versa.